Baking a Normal Map with details
It's not the first time that when I have to bake a normal map I lose a lot of detail. In the previous model, in the low poly mesh I had around 30k faces, in fact I could see the details.
Now in this new model I wanted to reduce the low poly faces for better optimization.
The problem is that I can't get enough detail from the high poly mesh. What can I do?
Another thing is that i retopologized the mesh with Instant meshes so it isn't perfect. I attach an image with uv grid so you can see the seams.
In case you want to try to view the problem you can download the file here:
https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/db3f1890-0752-4148-b833-fa38f84c4a7b







Why are you using max ray distance?

it seems to work fine, I've applied the scale of the high-poly, I've created a new image (32-Bit Float) and baked without cage and with an Extrusion value of 0.01, here is the result:


thank you so much!
